# git revert error message using SublimeText

Tags: git, sublimetext2, sublimetext, revert, git-revert

I'm working my way through a git tutorial and ran into a problem when trying to use **git revert**. Anytime I try to use the **git revert** command I receive the following message:

> sublimetext -wl1: sublimetext: command not found
>   error: There was a problem with the editor 'sublimetext -wl1'.
>   Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

I'm using SublimeText 2.0.2, bash, and a macbook.

I'm probably missing something very simple but I haven't been able to find any documentation addressing this issue so far.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You likely have set the editor Git uses for commit messages incorrectly. Try doing `git config -g --unset core.editor`.

Comment: Is this the preferred way to setup a text editor for bash? I haven't done any previous bash configuration besides assigning a name and email for git.

Comment: Tried @poke's suggestion anyways, received ``error: unknown switch `g'``.

Comment: Oops, it’s actually `git config --global --unset core.editor`. Anyway, this will unset the configuration for the editor Git will use, so it will give you *vim* as an editor as default. If that works then, you can see what you can do to correctly set up sublime text as the editor for Git.